# Limitation in odbcCloseAll

Tags: r, odbc

My R script has to do a lot of Excel open/write/close/open/read/close, with things in the middle, and I use for that the `RODBC` package. There seems to be an issue with `odbcCloseAll` which won't close opened Excel connections after a number of times.
Simple example (hopefully reproducible and not just because my PC is weird):

```
require(RODBC)
filename <- tempfile(fileext='.xls')
for(i in 1:100) {
xlsFile <- odbcConnectExcel(filename, readOnly=FALSE)
sqlSave(xlsFile, USArrests, rownames = FALSE)
odbcCloseAll()
xlsFile <- odbcConnectExcel(filename, readOnly=FALSE)
template <- sqlFetch(xlsFile, "USArrests")
odbcCloseAll()
file.remove(filename)
}
```

And at some point (around `i = 50` in my case), the loop crashes with:

```
Error in sqlSave(xlsFile, USArrests, rownames = FALSE) : 
  table ‘USArrests’ already exists
In addition: Warning message:
In file.remove(filename) :
  cannot remove file 'c:\DOCUME~1\user\LOCALS~1\Temp\RtmpSFDDiG\file43522f58.xls', reason 'Permission denied'
```

The problem can easily be solved using `odbcClose(xlsFile)`, or any other package linking to Excel, but for the sake of correctness, I'm wondering what is wrong with `odbcCloseAll`...

Comment: FWIW, my PC laptop produces the same error.  Using `options(error=recover)` to debug, I see also that `file.remove(filename)` doesn't work, for `i=52` in my case. Strange.

Comment: I also tried it and I get the same error. Also I'm not able to open the file in excel, as I would have expected.

Comment: It seems that when RODBC Connection > 100, odbcCloseAll doesn't close them anymore. ?? Limit to < 100 connections for odbcCloseAll ?? Mayby ask the dev if there is such a limit.

Comment: It seems that the limit should be 1000 not 100 ?? From the documentation: In
addition, a C-level table keeps the pointers of the first 1000 connections of
an R session, to enable odbcCloseAll to close them.     http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, in the C source, there is an error in the C code:

```
 SEXP RODBCCloseAll(void)
 {
     int i;

     for(i = 1; i <= my_min(nChannels, 100); i++) <<<===== error
        if(opened_handles[i])
                  inRODBCClose(opened_handles[i]);

     return R_NilValue;
 }
```

should be

```
 SEXP RODBCCloseAll(void)
 {
     int i;

     for(i = 1; i <= my_min(nChannels, 1000); i++) <<<=====
        if(opened_handles[i])
              inRODBCClose(opened_handles[i]);

     return R_NilValue;
 }
```

I'll email the developer. In the mean time you can rebuild the package with this change. 
The error is on line 1235.

Comment: Thanks Mischa for taking the time to dig into the source. That explains everything. However my aforementioned loop will still crash if we have `i in 1:10000`...

Comment: The limit is 1000. The code stores the first 1000 connections. If you want to change that to 10.000, that will require more changes. At what iteration do you get the crash? i = 1001? or somewhere in the neighbourhood?

Comment: There is also in the code these lines:      if(nChannels <= 1000) opened_handles[nChannels] = thisHandle;   and     if(thisHandle->channel <= 1000) opened_handles[thisHandle->channel] = NULL;
on lines 273 and 1200 that limit the number of stored channels. There might be others still. I don't know